# Accessing mpp file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ms-project, mpxj

I need to access and get data from `.mpp file`(MS Project). Anyone tell me if there is a node module available to access mpp ?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, however I am planning to write a JavaScript wrapper for MPXJ for use with Node.js. It would work on the same basis as the Ruby wrapper, i.e. the actual processing work is carried out by an external Java process, with the results being delivered back to JavaScript as JSON, with JavaScript classes providing access to the data contained in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for response Jon Iles. I done this task using MPXJ librarys.

Comment: Hi Jon Iles, Can i have some of your work samples where you implemented MPXJ for node modules?

Comment: have you made this.?

Comment: @HardikRanpariya Did you get any clue on this?

Comment: @Aravinth can you tell me how you have achieved with this MPXJ library?

Answer (score 0):

Aspose has [Cloud API](https://products.aspose.cloud/tasks/nodejs) to manipulate MS Project files (including MPP format). There is a Javascript SDK for Cloud API that is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@asposecloud/aspose-tasks-cloud):

> npm i @asposecloud/aspose-tasks-cloud

The Cloud API calls [are billable](https://purchase.aspose.cloud/pricing) after some threshold.

PS: I am a developer at Aspose.